# Add a randomised body class

Tags: random

I need to add a random class from a selection of pre-defined classes to the body tag of a template.

I did it with JS but the change is visible so I would like to do it before the page is rendered.

Any ideas?

Many thanks
Mikee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Low Random](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-random) maybe?

`{exp:low_random:item items="cat|dog|ferret|raptor"}`

Comment: Yup, that is ideal!

Answer (score 3):

[Low Random](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-random/docs#item-tag) looks like it'd do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Inefficient I guess but you could use channel entries with a random sort order, a matrix field with the same or I think Low Variables would be the most efficient way.

Comment: Do you mean that Low Random will be inefficient or using channel entries?

Comment: I meant using channel entries. Glad to see the answer - learned something new today : )

Answer (score 0):

People have mentioned low Random, but the Randomizer plugin can also be used to add strings to just about anything (images, text, whole paragraphs, a class...) It's lightweight, it's easy to use (though you have to edit the PHP file to build the arrays) and it will insert the content before the page is rendered.